# radio button is not clickable in android after initialize in the java class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a radio button in a java android application. I have declared and initialized the radio button and everything seems perfect but when I click the radio button the println console outputs nothing. Below is a snippet of my attempt

`RadioButton first, second;` //initialized the first radio button

//below was called in the oncreate method

```
first= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.first);
second= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.second);
```

//on clicking any of the radio buton nothing happens

```
if(first.isSelected()){
   System.out.println("the  first is here");
 }else if (second.isSelected()){
   System.out.println("the second is here ");
 }
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you set the radio button listener for the click/change event?

Comment: Its better to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for radio button instead of on click event of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way is to use RadioGroup and set the listener.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
        }
    });
```

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-radio-button-example

Always use the radio group if there are two or more than two radio buttons in the screen.

**Why to use radio group?**

If we check one radio button that belongs to a radio group, it automatically unchecks any previously checked radio button within the same group.

Answer (score 0):

try this user RadioGroup

```
        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/cancle_booking_radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBetterDeal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/found_a_better_deal" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDiffHotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/want_to_book_a_differnt_hotel" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBookingMistake"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/booking_created_by_mistake" />
  </RadioGroup>
```

now set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of `RadioGroup` like this

```
  final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancle_booking_radio_group);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
            int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                   // radio button one selected
                    break;
                case 1:
                   // radio button two selected
                    break;
                case 2:
                   // radio button Three selected
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
```